# Is there a c++ analyzer to give member variables modified/used/referenced by a function

Tags: c++, ide, clion, static-analysis

A function's side effect is to change global variables. For c, it can be only global variables or static variables. But c++, a member function often modifies a member variable. Is there a way to give a summary which member variables are modified/used/referenced by a function?
I'm using Scitools Understand. It is a great tool, but I cannot get which member variables are modified/used/referenced by a function. It only gives use of global variables. For c, it may be enough. But c++ has member variables.
[image]

Comment: If your functions are long enough to need such a tool, you should consider smaller functions. If you can’t look at it and quickly understand what it’s doing and what it touches, it’s too long

Comment: Sorry, but software, library, or tool recommendation requests are not appropriate questions for Stackoverflow.